# Password verify always returns fail in Laravel (Hash::check)

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords

I've got an issue when I try to validate the post password via **Hash::check** in Laravel 5.5

I made a posts table (in this case sales table) with password column. When I try to create the post, it's working perfectly and the password is hashed and also belongs to logged in User. Then on the current post page is a button with an input (password) to delete that specific post, but the condition is always false.

My **Controller** public function destroy(Request $request, $id)

```
$input_pass = request('input_password');

    $sale = Sale::find($id);
    $hashed = $sale->password;

    // Check if sale password is correct
    if (Hash::check($input_pass, $sale->password)) {

    $sale->delete();

    } else {
        // something else to do
    }
```

For the post store, I used bcrypt method to hash the password. I've been also trying to dd('sale->password') which refers to column in sales table (correct) and dd('$input_pass') which refers to typed in password in DELETE form (also correct) - so I'm a little bit confused, why the pass don't match.

Comment: post the bit of code where you bycrypt the password

Comment: $sale = Sale::forceCreate([
         'sale_title' => request('sale_title'),
         'password' => bcrypt('password'),
         'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
        ]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment I find that you have a logical error where you initially hash your password and persist it in DB.

You are passing the string `password` to `bcrypt` where it should actually be something like `request('password')`

Change

```
'password' => bcrypt('password'),
```

to

```
'password' => bcrypt(request('password')),
```